# Convert string with form "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm" to joda datetime in dataframe in Spark

Tags: scala, datetime, apache-spark, jodatime

I'm reading in csv-files with in one column a string that should be converted to a datetime. The string is in the form `MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm`. However when I try to transform this using joda-time, I always get the error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Schema for type org.joda.time.DateTime is not supported

I don't know what exactly the problem is...

```
 val input = c.textFile("C:\\Users\\AAPL.csv").map(_.split(",")).map{p => 
      val formatter: DateTimeFormatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm");
      val date: DateTime = formatter.parseDateTime(p(0));
      StockData(date, p(1).toDouble, p(2).toDouble, p(3).toDouble, p(4).toDouble, p(5).toInt, p(6).toInt)
}.toDF()
```

Anybody who can help?

Answer (score 5):

> I don't know what exactly the problem is...

Well, the source of the problem is pretty much described by an error message. Spark SQL doesn't support Joda-Time `DateTime` as an input. A valid input for a date field is `java.sql.Date` (see [Spark SQL and DataFrame Guide, Data Types for reference](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#data-types)).

The simplest solution is to adjust `StockData` class so it takes `java.sql.Data` as an argument and replace:

```
val date: DateTime = formatter.parseDateTime(p(0))
```

with something like this:

```
val date: java.sql.Date = new java.sql.Date(
  formatter.parseDateTime(p(0)).getMillis)
```

or

```
val date: java.sql.Timestamp = new java.sql.Timestamp(
  formatter.parseDateTime(p(0)).getMillis)
```

if you want to preserve hour / minutes.

If you think about using window functions with range clause a better option is to pass string to a DataFrame and convert it to an integer timestamp:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.unix_timestamp

df.withColumn("ts", unix_timestamp($"date", "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm"))
```

See [Spark Window Functions - rangeBetween dates](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33207164/1560062) for details.

Comment: Hmm, OP can load the date as a String and then convert to a DateType too right (since their goal is to have this as a DataFrame)?

Comment: True, although I think it requires intermediate `timestamp` in this case. `to_date` doesn't take format string, and simple `cast(DateType)` will fail due to invalid input format. Do you see any other option?

Comment: [UDF](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29909448/add-new-column-in-dataframe-base-on-existing-column)? Or is that overkill?

Comment: Maybe a little, but why not? Personally I would probably go with integer timestamps especially considering [the previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/33650880/1560062).

Comment: 'val dateFormat: DateFormat  = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm")
val date: java.sql.Timestamp = new Timestamp(dateFormat.parse(p(0)).getTime)' Thanks a lot! with Timestamp I get exactly what I want, thank you for setting me on the right track